# Do I need Hadoop in my windows to connect on hbase running on linux?

Tags: linux, eclipse, hadoop, hbase, kundera

Do I need Hadoop in my windows to connect on hbase running on ununtu with hadoop?

My hbase is running fine on my ubuntu machine. I am able to connect with eclipse on same machine ( I am using kundera to connect hbase). Now I want to connect hbase from my windows 7 eclipse IDE . Do I need to install hadoop on my windows to connect remote hbase which is on ubuntu .?? when I tried I am getting  something like this

```
Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path
Read about open-source technology .IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries.
```

Answer (score 2):

All you need are the hadoop, hbase jars and then Configuration object initialized 
with:
1. hbase.zookeeper.quorum(if cluster) details and other information initialized.
2. hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort
3. zookeeper.znode.parent

And then, getting connection with the above config object

Comment: Thanks .. Do I need these in my windows machine??  i  have added all jars (pom.xml maven project) . Can please elaborate little

Comment: yes, a stanalone java project, with jars, and config details above should be fine, to use Put, Scan etc

Answer (score 1):

This problem usually occurs in Hadoop 2.x.x version. One of the option is to build Windows distribution for Hadoop version. 
Refer this link:
http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/38/build-install-configure-run-apache-hadoop-2.2.0-microsoft-windows-os

But, before building try to use the zip file given in this link:

http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/39/error-util-shell-failed-locate-winutils-binary-hadoop-binary-path

Extract this zip file and paste the files under hadoop-common-2.2.0/bin to $HADOOP_HOME/bin directory.

Note: For me this works even for Hadoop 2.5 version.